# Using onListItemClick with data driven ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which its contents could change at any time (eg. a list of cities within a state; a new city could be added to the state in our database at anytime). How do I implement, if possible, the onListItemClick event to work with this? For example, if a user selects a certain city in the ListView, i should be able to pass a value that independently identifies what city was clicked onto my next activity. I can't listen for positions because they could change with an addition or removal of a city. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you must write your own Adapter (for instance, extending the [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)) and overwrite the `getItemId` method:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int posicion) {
    return somethingThatIdentifyTheCityThatWasClicked;
}
```

The rest will be piece of cake since the `onListItemClick` method gets that ID:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID) 
{    
    // use the 'thisID' variable
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out and get back to you, but it looks like it's just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Can you explain in a little more depth?